# How to get the output of a program into a Hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I've a code that goes like this:

```
public static void displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
    try {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().endsWith(".svn")) {
                System.out.println("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
                displayDirectoryContents(file);
            } else {
                System.out.println("file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, is there a way to put the result set into a hashmap?

Comment: What will be the key, value pairs here? It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You use a hashmap if you want to associate some keys with some values.  If all you have is a list of file paths you don't have key/value pairs.  Tell us what you are trying to accomplish (not just "put file paths into a hashmap").

Comment: My key and values are same, i.e the result of the above written code. This code gives out the files and their file paths that are stored inside a particular folder (I've only posted a part of the code here). So whatever the output it gives has to be stored in a hashmap with key and values being the same.

Comment: Please edit the question with what you want the resulting HashMap to look like

Comment: My key and values are same, i.e the result of the above written code. This code gives out the files and their file paths that are stored inside a particular folder (I've only posted a part of the code here). So whatever the output it gives has to be stored in a hashmap with key and values being the same i.e. the file paths.

Comment: Which version of Java?

Comment: you can introduce `Map<String, Object>`, and as `Object`  you can put either `String` (for file), or `Map<String, Object>` for folder, and make recursion. or simply make a List of files, and recursively populate it. with pure file paths,  and folders are ignored.

Comment: There is no purpose of storing both keys and values if they are the same. The reason you use a HashMap is to do key-value lookup. If they are the same, then you'll be looking up the value using the value itself. A filesystem is a Tree data-structure. Nodes are files&directories, Parents are directories. Leaves are files and empty directories. Node values are file/directory names

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of nesting of objects, so hashmap could be not so good data structure. I would suggest to introduce the custom POJO and tree-like structure:

```
class Node { String canonicalPath; String type; Node parent; List<Node> children = new ArrayList<>(); }
```

And modified your code :

```
public List<Node> displayDirectoryContents(File dir, Node parent) {

List<Node> result = new ArrayList<Node>();
try {
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().endsWith(".svn")) {
            Node directory = new Node(file.getCanonicalPath(), "directory", parent);
            directory.setChildren(displayDirectoryContents(file, directory);
            result.add( directory );
        } else {
            result.add(new Node(file.getCanonicalPath(), "file", parent);
        }
    }
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return result;
}
```

something like that - and modify than your processing.

or if you need file list with its names :

you can introduce `Map<String, Object>`, and as `Object`  you can put either `String` (for file), or `Map<String, Object>` for folder, and make recursion.

or simply make a `List` of files, and recursively populate it. with pure file paths,  like

```
List<String> displayDirectoryContents(File dir) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList();
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().endsWith(".svn")) {
            res.add("directory:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
            res.addAll(displayDirectoryContents(file));
        } else {
            res.add("file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

and than you can:

`displayDirectoryContents("/dummypath").forEach(System.out.println);`

will give you the same result.

Or to Concurrent map of string-string

`Map<String, String> res = displayDirectoryContents("/dummypath").stream().collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(o -> o, o -> o));`

Comment: Appreciate your help, but what I need is a hashmap only so that I can compare the entries for any duplicacy.